# UIButton setAutoresizingMask not working programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm adding a UIButton in code, but when I test it on different devices the button doesn't resize and reposition itself correctly, however when I add the same button on a Storyboard it behaves properly...  The storyboard does not have Autolayout enabled...

EDIT3: Added photo of UI below, the larger "Basics 2" button is the storyboard defined one....the rest are defined in code

[image: Ui photo]

EDIT2: When I look at the Storyboard XML for the button that behaves correctly it's defined like this, full storyboard XML now below

```
<button hidden="YES" autoresizesSubviews="NO" opaque="NO" contentMode="center" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="ujO-uz-KyO">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="30" y="100" width="116" height="70"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES" heightSizable="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                            <inset key="imageEdgeInsets" minX="0.0" minY="27" maxX="72" maxY="0.0"/>
                                            <state key="normal" image="greenp.png" backgroundImage="basics2.png">
                                                <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                            </state>
                                        </button>
```

I add the button like this (Edited to use the code suggested below, still doesn't work)

```
  UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  button1.frame = [[butLocArr objectAtIndex:x] CGRectValue];
  button1.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
  [button1 setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |

UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
//The view is a UiScrollView
 [scrollChallengeView addSubview:button1];
```

The storyboard added button, which behaves correctly, is setup like this, where am i going wrong?

[image]

Comment: the storyboard definition doesn't match the interface builder UI.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes I know, but that's how I have it setup, there seems to be some confusion over this http://iurl.no/39b45

Comment: could you actually add a screenshot of your UI so that we can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Sulthan Screenshot added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` and  `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`

```
[button1 setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

When you add button in IB with AutoresizingMask it's autoresize after lunch. For example, screen width increases from 320 (in storyboard) to 540px (on device) and button size increases proportionally. When you add button programmatically it's just added and you should calculate button size manually according to screen size. Autoresizing button will be calling on rotating. So you width and height should be calculated like this:

```
CGFloat width  = k1 * [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
CGFloat height = k2 * width;
```

Comment: That's it!  I was adjusting the baseline X and Y positions of the UIButtons based on screen-size, but not the width and height. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you too, it's my first bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleMargins`

i.e

```
[button1 setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleMargins];
```

or

```
[button1 setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```

instead

```
[button1 setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Comment: I've tried the 2nd suggestion but it doesn't work... ;(

Comment: Yeah i saw that...but no combination seems to duplicate the Button created in the Storyboard, I've edited my original post to include the XML from the button created in the Storyboard..

Answer (score 0):

In that IB setup you've got:

- flexible margins (top, left, bottom and right);
- flexible size (width and height);

So the autoresizing mask should be

```
button1.autoresizingMask =
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |

    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: Is `[[butLocArr objectAtIndex:x] CGRectValue];` returns `CGRectMake(30, 100, 116, 70)`?

Comment: Is `view` in `[view addSubview:button1]` the same view as in IB?

Comment: Yes I'm adding it to a scrollview, the same view as in the Storyboard

Comment: In which UIViewController method the button is created? `viewDidLoad`? Can you post a gist with controller initialization methods?

Comment: Not in viewDidLoad, afterwards. It runs a few seconds after startup, once a webView is finished loading...

Comment: Then it is possible that `bounds` rect of the button's container view did change due to UIViewController's `view` lifecycle, specifically to adapting its `frame` to device screen size and position. So at the point when the button is added as subview to that container view, this view's `bounds` rect differs from those in IB. Autoresizing takes this into account, resulting in different size and position of the button. You have to add your button in `viewDidLoad` (where `view.frame` is not yet modified) or calculate deltas for position and size by yourself.